# make algolia query which finds a close enough name or a matching tag

Tags: javascript, algolia

```
const search =(nameInput, inputTags)=>{
  index.search('', {
    filters: ''
  }).then(({ hits }) => {
    console.log(hits);
  })
}
```

im trying to to create a query thats close to : (have a "name_field" close enough to nameInput or match atleast one of the inputTags array elements to "tags_field"

Comment: Did you look at https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/guides/filtering-results/#applying-filters-from-tags?